# Display turn on automatically after time out

Tags: display

Display auto time out after the given time. Even when locking Ubuntu, automatically fading and turn off the display.
But after couple of seconds display automatically turn on without mouse or keyboard input.

- After lock the pc -

  it turns on to black screen after couple of seconds (mouse is clearly visible in black screen), after key board or mouse input, lock screen appears.
- After I run -

  ```
  xset dpms force off
  ```

  it turn off the display instantly and after couple of seconds display turn on again and shows where I was.

How can I prevent display from auto turning on ?

Hardware : Dell inspiron-3543

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Try command

```
sleep 2 && xset dpms force off
```

That way you have two seconds time to raise up the return key before the actual display management command runs. Otherwise keyboard activity will turn the display back on.

I do not know which command you use for locking, but you could use the same technique with it. Some locking commands may be able to take the issue into account without the trick.